# Loop & lookup 3 criteria in another sheet and fill data in empty column when criteria is fulfilled

Tags: excel, vba

What i'm trying to achieve is to loop through all rows of data in Detail tab and lookup to identify the lines that exact match to the Tracker tab. Once the row of data in tracker tab is identified, then set a copy of value from Column L to Column S of the same row.

I have previously tried to achieve with VLOOKUP method on the ICN No. column but as it was only looking at one criteria, it did not match the correct line in tracker as the amount is different.

Please help!

Edit: I did a application.match coding but i don't know what is wrong with the code:

```
 Sub MatchPName_Amt_ICN()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim NumRow, LastRow As Long
    Dim Sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sPRng, sARng, sICNRng As Variant

    Set Sht1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Detail")

    LastRow = Sheets("Tracker").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    NumRow = Sht1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

        For Each cell In Sheets("Tracker").Range("F2" & ":V" & LastRow)
            sPRng = Application.Match(1, Sht1.Range("H2" & ":H" & NumRow), 0)
            sARng = Application.Match(1, Sht1.Range("P2" & ":P" & NumRow), 0)
            sICNRng = Application.Match(1, Sht1.Range("V2" & ":V" & NumRow), 0)

                If Not IsError( _
                    sPRng = cell(0, "F").Value & _
                    sARng = cell(0, "L").Value & _
                    sICNRng = cell(0, "R").Value) Then

                    If cell(0, "V").Value = "" Then                    'If Tracker column V is empty
                    cell(0, "V").Value = cell.Offset(0, -10).Value    'The cell value = column L
                    End If
                End If
    Next cell

    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

[Excel file](https://ufile.io/7uhwt)

The uploaded file is different from my working file as there are some P&C info which i have to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which columns from which sheets go where?

Comment: For Tracker tab's Column S to copy value from same row Column L.

Comment: To the details tab?

Comment: I think what you need is an index match formula,  see the formula below.  `=INDEX(Detail!$L$2:$L$237,MATCH(R41612&Q41612,Detail!$V$2:$V$237&Detail!$U$2:$U$237,0))`  this is just a formula and not vba, but you can use it in vba by using the evaluate function.  This index match version is based on multiple criteria, it is a step more complicated than a regular index match formula, see the link that i have attached for a better explanation:  https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/  .  Also, is the detail tab complete?

Comment: Hi, i wanted the copy value to happen in the Tracker's tab after looking up if the details tab data is present.

Comment: put this in the column s of the tracker tab.  `=INDEX(Detail!$L$2:$L$237,MATCH(Tracker!R42675&Tracker!F42675,Detail!$V$2:$V$237&Detail!$H$2:$H$237,0))`  put your cursor in the formula and press control shift and enter together.  for this I put it in column s of row 42675 to test against values that were actually present in the details tab.  REMEBER CONTROL SHIFT AND ENTER TOGETHER WITH THE CURSOR IN THE FORMULA.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: `=INDEX(Detail!$L$2:$L$237,MATCH(Tracker!R42690&Tracker!F42690&Tracker!G42690&Tracker!H42690,Detail!$V$2:$V$237&Detail!$H$2:$H$237&Detail!$I$2:$I$237&Detail!$J$2:$J$237,0))` Using the instructions from above, this is the same idea but with four criteria instead of two.  Try this one and it should work great. Thanks!

Comment: The thing is in my working file, there are some values which i would like to retain thus i wanted a VBA script to validate the criteria AND see if the column S is empty.

Comment: This can be inserted into your vba script using the evaluate method https://bettersolutions.com/excel/functions/vba-evaluate.htm.